# BitCoin Api, Result Keys,BitCoin Protocol documentation

Tags: transactions, api, blockchain.info

I am developing android application using https ://blockchain.info/api. i am having problem to understand the Keywords used in result for https: //blockchain.info/address/$bitcoin_address?format=json.

Can any one tell me about the Keys hilighted. I want to show user Transaction history. Any Documentation reference will be helpful. I have also read https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation but it was not help full.

[image]Thanks